# How can this BootstrapVue table override the app css?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a simple BootstrapVue table.

The css is defined in `App.vue`. Here's the code for `App.vue`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png"> -->
    <TestTable msg="testing"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestTable from './components/TestTable.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    TestTable
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;  
}
</style>
```

Here's the code for `TestTable.vue`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `margin-top: 60px` is defined in `App.vue`. I want to modify `TableTest.vue` such that it overrides the margin top in the CSS in `App.vue`. I want `margin-top: 0px` for `TableTest.vue`.

I am using Vue v2.6 and Bootstrap-vue.

Comment: You applied margin from top on parent div. Hence, as child div is separate it will not work. You can apply margin in negative but that is not a good practice to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to modify TableTest.vue such that it overrides the margin top in the CSS in App.vue

I earlier commented on your question that you applied `margin-top: 60px` in your parent component and child component is having its own box model.

Adding a code snippet to show how your component structured:

```js
Vue.component('item', {
  template:'#list-template',
  props:['item'],
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  computed: {
    limitedItems() {
      return ['item1'];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <item v-for="item in limitedItems" :item="item" style="border: 2px solid green"></item>
</div>

<template id="list-template">
  <p>{{ item }}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Upvoted. I was hoping to have some magical keyword that can allow a child single-file-component(SFC) style to ignore the parent's style. The parent SFC's style may not be desired by some children SFC.

Comment: Why can't You just use #app { margin-top: 0 } in your Table component?

Answer (score 0):

you can try  `margin-top: -60px;`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
<style>
 #app {
   margin-top: 0;
 }
</style>
```

In Your `TestTable.vue` file and it will overwrite the previous css rule given that both `<style>` tags are not scoped.